# JavaScript object array not properly sorting

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I have this object array

```
var grps = [{
    group_no: 0,
    id: "733",
    xpos: 226.72,
    ypos: 100
}, {
    group_no: 0,
    id: "735",
    xpos: -1.19,
    ypos: 200
}];
```

and im trying to sort the array based on  value xpos

```
var small_x = grps.sort(function(a, b) {
    return a.xpos - b.xpos;
});
```

and when i do

```
 console.log(small_x[0].xpos); //sort asc
```

I expect the value to be `-1.19` but iam getting `226.72`

Comment: Seems works fine http://jsfiddle.net/5pbkddgo/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/cz7sasct/ - looks fine

Comment: @ArunPJohny is there any way it is not sorting correctly because of string

Comment: @coolguy—the *xpos* property is a number, so strings aren't your issue. Even if the values are strings like  `'-1.19'` it will still work OK as the `-` operator coerces the operands to Number anyway (e.g. you can sort by *id* too even though the values are strings like `"735"`).

Comment: @coolguy yes... if it is doing a string comparison try http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/cz7sasct/3/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See below (works also for string values). The ECMA script doesn't specify which algoritm has been used. But, simply said, compare posx of a is <, > or (else) == posx of b. This returns resp. -1, 1 or 0, which could be sort simply.

See also the documentation of Mozilla Developer Network with description, examples, ECMA script notes, and the example below (conceptual): https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

```
function comparePos(a, b)
{
   if (a.xpos < b.xpos)
      return -1;
   if (a.xpos > b.xpos)
      return 1;
   return 0;
}

grps.sort(comparePos);
```

See this: [Sort array of objects by string property value in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1129216/sort-array-of-objects-by-string-property-value-in-javascript)